# Sorting discrete random variables using joint probability distribution

Tags: random-variables, relations

There are 3 discrete random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$. They each take $n$ possible values, $n \leq 10$. So their joint pmf Then their joint [PMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) $p(X, Y, Z) \in \mathbb{R}^{n^3}$ is a histogram of $n^3$ bins, which are all non-negative and sum up to 1. I want to introduce the comparison operation '$\geq$' that would allow me to sort the random variables in non-ascending order, for example

$$X \geq Z \geq Y$$

The relational operation should satisfy the standard requirements such as

- antisymmetry: $(X \geq Y) \& (Y \geq X) \rightarrow X=Y$
- transitivity: $(X \geq Y) \& (Y \geq Z) \rightarrow X \geq Z$
- reflexivity: $X \geq X$ holds $\forall X$

It should use all of the available information to perform the comparison, namely, $X = Y$ if and only if $P(X,Y,Z) = P(Y,X,Z)$, otherwise one of them should be larger than the other. The question is to find an example of such operation and present an algorithm on how to compute it. I wonder if such operation already exists in the literature. If yes, I would appreciate a link.

Finally, I have another requirement. I don't know how to formalize it yet, so for this question I will not require it to be satisfied. However, it would be great if the comparison operation was performed in a sensible way, comparing big things first and small things later. If we consider comparing decimal numbers as analogy, we could introduce an operation that compares them starting with the right-most digit, and moving to the left. That operation would satisfy all of the criteria, but it would ignore large fluctuations and focus on small fluctuations, which makes the order valid but somewhat meaningless.

Comment: Your definition of antisymmetry looks weird are you sure it is what you mean? Beside what doesn't you talk of reflexivity?

Comment: @EtienneBfx I'm sorry, I had formal mathematics many years ago. What do you find weird about asymmetry? Can you remind me what reflexivity is again? How would you write the requirements? It should behave normally, as one would expect of inequality applied to e.g. real numbers

Comment: Antisymmetry is $X>Y$ and $Y>X$ implies $X=Y$ and reflexivity is $X>X$ for all $X$. With transitivity, they are the three axioms of an inequality.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand reflexivity. Why should $X > X$ hold? $X$ can't be greater than itself, right? I want to distinguish strict and non-strict inequality

Comment: The philosophy is to work with "greater or equal" more than "strictly greater" because it has nicer properties

Comment: Maybe look at the second answer of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678737/im-not-understanding-what-a-reflexive-set-is

Comment: Ok, I edited. Hope this is good

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on what you want : you want a relation between some random variables, is that right? If so, then there are many orders (stochastic domination order, hazard rate order, logconcave order, etc.). But all of them are *partial* orders, so sometimes you won't be able to sort the random variables in any order.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks for mentioning the many orders, I was not aware of them. Yes, I want a relation between random variables. The important part of my question is that the order must be able to make use of joint PMF. I have had a quick look at stochastic domination, and it is good, except that it only compares marginal probability distributions, ignoring any possible statistical dependence. Is this right? Can you suggest an order that takes relations into account. Also, could you elaborate on your last point. What do you mean that sometimes I won't be able to sort at all?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins On an order taking relations into account : I will have to think about that. On the last point : The point is ,if you give me two random variables $X$ and $Y$, it is possible that both $X \not \leq Y$ and $Y \not \leq X$ be true in the stochastic order, so they could be incomparable. Your program would either fail to find an order here, or output "no order possible". But you want something that always produces an order, right?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes, it is essential that the order can always be estimated. I'm sure it can be done. For example, if we only have 2 variables, then a valid order could be generated by comparing upper vs lower triangular parts of the PMF matrix lexicographically. However, there are two problems: 1) How to extend this to 3 variables? 2) It's not very meaningful. If the first element in the lexicographical order is different, the rest of the elements will have no impact on the order. But there is nothing special about 1st element. Order would depend on enumeration of states, which is meaningless

Comment: @AleksejsFomins For $3$ variables, I would expect a lexicographic order as well, right? It's like ordering three-letter words, I would think. As for the second point : yes, it is not meaningful, unfortunately. This is the trade-off : if you wish to compare random variables meaningfully, then you will have to trade meaning with totality : you can't compare every pair of variables, but those that you can compare, you can deduce very useful results for them. If you want a total order , it is just going to look a little meaningless.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Why is such a tradeoff present? Is it not possible to have a meaningful full comparison e.g. by using some sort of frequency transform like legendre basis on the matrix elements? Is there some sort of theoretical result or at least an intuition as to why this can't be done?

Comment: Great question, Aleksejs. I cannot really say why this occurs, but what I think is this : demanding a total order means that we have to introduce properties that aren't "natural in thought" i.e. they are not meaningful w.r.t the subject we are studying. Introducing artificially, a certain property that isn't "naturally" present creates an issue in both applicability as well as how flexible such a theory can be. Bottom line : orders which are less constrained appear more naturally and are more useful in modelling real-life phenomena. No rigorous explanation, of course.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks a lot for your insight. If this is indeed true, I would have to abandon this line of solution. You see, I want to perform embedding/clustering on some sets of empirically obtained PMFs in order to see of they have certain similarities (e.g. tSNE). However, these PMF's possess information about the order of the variables, which is a nuisance in this case. I was hoping to get rid of it. But maybe I can look for a different solution, e.g. by decomposing PMFs into some meaningful series expansion first.

Comment: You are welcome! (I have given you a +1 long ago) Whatever it is, I'm mightily impressed by your question. Unfortunately I don't know what to do about this one because you wish to change your line of thinking, but I will keep a tab on your questions in the future, because thankfully our backgrounds seem to match somewhat.